# Web API read header value in controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to get at the header information in the constructor of a web API controller?  I want to set variables based off a header value but I don't want to have to do it for each method.  I'm particularly interested in a custom header value but I would settle for the Authorization one at this point.  I can get it to work in an `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` but I also need it at the controller level.

```
[PolicyAuthorize]
public class PoliciesController : ApiController
{
    public PoliciesController()
    {
        var x = HttpContext.Current;  //will be null in constructor
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var x = HttpContext.Current;  //will be available but too late
    }
}

public class PolicyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;  //can get at Authorization header here but no HTTPActionContext in controller
    }
}
```

Comment: I used System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers for this porpose

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following are some options that you can consider...prefer `1.` over `2.`

1. Store additional data in current request message's properties bag `HttpRequestMessage.Properties` and have a convenience property in controller which all actions in the controller can access.

   ```
   [CustomAuthFilter]
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
       public string Name
       {
           get
           {
               return Request.Properties["Name"].ToString();
           }
       }

       public string GetAll()
       {
           return this.Name;
       }
   }

   public class CustomAuthFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
   {
       public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           actionContext.Request.Properties["Name"] = "<your value from header>";
       }
   }
   ```
2. You could get the current controller's instance and set the property value. Example:

   ```
   [CustomAuthFilter]
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public string GetAll()
       {
           return this.Name;
       }
   }

   public class CustomAuthFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
   {
       public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           ValuesController valuesCntlr = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as ValuesController;

           if (valuesCntlr != null)
           {
               valuesCntlr.Name = "<your value from header>";
           }
       }
   }
   ```